# How do I get the id of the selected row from my database in a datagridview control?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, .net-2.0, windows-forms-designer

this is my data grid view

[image]

I want to get the ID when a row is selected but when I select a row and click delete it doesn't seem to get the id of that row and goes for the else statement instead. here is my code. why does it not get the ID when selected?

```
MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        int ID = 0;

        if ( ID != 0)
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("delete from vehicle where ID=@id", conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully!");
            int rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Delete");
        }
```

Comment: CurrentCell has a Value property. Based on your screenshot that should return 1 as an object which you can cast to an int. Most simple to solve the current problem: `int rowIndex = (int) dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value;` Don't ask what happens if you select a different cell and then delete but you can also access Rows with the RowIndex and then get the column value you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your ID will never be anything other than 0 at the time the `if` is tested, so your code will always go for the `else`

```
    int ID = 0;

    if ( ID != 0)
    {
```